# Core Data between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm confused on how to pass the selected objectAtIndexPath into the detail view controller. The root view controller is a table view of athletes. when selected, I want the detail view controller (the controller that would be pushed into the navigation stack) to know all about what was just selected, e.g. all the attributes, name, phone, etc. i'm just confused on what to pass. here is what I have.

tableview.h

```
//how I populate the table
    -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        _managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];

        NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *athlete = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Athlete" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
        [request setEntity:athlete];
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"last" ascending:YES];
        NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
        if (mutableFetchResults == nil){
            //handle error
        }
        [self setAthleteArray:mutableFetchResults];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }


//how I try to send, and fail
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSString *segueIdentifier = [segue identifier];
    if ([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"setAthlete"])
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        /*
        Athlete *athlete = [self.athleteArray objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        I cant send the array, what do I do?
    }
}
```

I dont have a fetched results view controller btw. and thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In **Athlete.h**

```
@interface Athlete : UIViewController
{
    NSArray *arrayList;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSArray *arrayList;

@end
```

synthesize arraylist  in .m

```
@synthesize arrayList;
```

In **tableview.h**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    NSString *segueIdentifier = [segue identifier];
    if ([segueIdentifier isEqualToString:@"setAthlete"])
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

        Athlete *athlete = [[Athlete alloc] initWithNibName:@"Athlete" bundle:nil];
        athlete.arrayList= [self.athleteArray objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    }
}
```

Try this for more detail check this [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)